# Cannot access nfs share

Tags: postgresql, nfs, mount

On my Debian 8.4 system, I would like to run a postgres database. The data should reside on an NFS mounted folder.

```
# cat /etc/fstab
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/volume1/srvPostgres on /var/lib/postgresql type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,mountvers=3,mountport=892,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

I installed postgres using apt-get, therefore it creates a user. The destination folder has the correct ownership:

```
# ls -la /var/lib/postgresql/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx  3 postgres postgres 4096 May  2 12:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 44 root     root     4096 May  2 10:14 ..
drwxrwxrwx  3 postgres postgres 4096 May  2 12:12 9.4
```

Somehow, postgres is not allowed to write into the folder:

```
# su postgres
bash: /var/lib/postgresql/.bashrc: Permission denied

postgres$ touch /var/lib/postgresql/test
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/lib/postgresql/test’: Permission denied
```

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?
And what is the correct way (if even supported) to have postgres' data on an NFS share?

Comment: Is the first code block really the content of `/etc/fstab` or is it the output of `mount`?

Comment: As a side note, I would strongly recommend against putting database data on NFS, especially for production purposes for a performance and maintenance/reliability reasons.

Comment: @fvu: Okay. Would you recommend to backup data to an NFS share?

Comment: @Atmocreations yes, that's no problem at all, we back up most of our data via nfs.

Comment: Does the postgres user exist on the nfs server, with the same uid?

Comment: can you show the content of exports file?